# Swift: Animating a view (for in-app notifications) onto the screen for a few seconds before removing

Tags: ios, swift, banner

I am attempting to do what is described perfectly here: https://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner

I want to create a banner that pops down on the screen for a few seconds before being removed (or removed when it is tapped on). The above project is great up until iOS 9. After that and with iOS 10, the banner no longer works as predicted and either shows itself without an animation for a third of a second or it doesn't show.

How can I add a view that animates onto the screen and then back off to provide a user a quick "No Internet" notification in-app. I want to avoid using the notification center.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and created my own library for it: [MDNotificationView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MDNotificationView)

The example app on [GitHub](https://github.com/moritzdietsche/mdnotificationview) implements your idea. Here is a small snippet implementing it:

```
let view = MDNotificationCompactLayoutView()
view.textLabel.text = "No internet connection."

let notificationView = MDNotificationView(view: view)
notificationView.delegate = self
notificationView.show()

// MARK: - Notification View Delegate

func notificationDidShow(notificationView: MDNotificationView) {
    // Hide the notification view automatically after 5 seconds.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        notificationView.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me MDNotificationView source code?